# error Strings must use singlequote quotes react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new to the react-native development, I am using the rule `"quotes": [2, "double", { "avoidEscape": true }]` and still getting the single quote error, i am not sure why..

here are some part of my code:

.eslintrc:

```
{
"extends": "@react-native-community",
"rules": {
  "quotes": [2, "double", { "avoidEscape": true }]
  }
```

}

.eslintrc.js:

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true,
    amd: true,
    node: true,
  },
  root: true,
  extends: "@react-native-community",
  overrides: [],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: "latest",
    sourceType: "module",
  },
  rules: {
    quotes: [2, "double", { avoidEscape: true }],
  },
};
```

.eslintrc.json:

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es2021": true,
        "react-native/react-native": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "@react-native-community"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": "latest",
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react",
        "react-native"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "quotes": [2, "double", { "avoidEscape": true }]
    }
}
```

pageage.json:

```
{
  "name": "mealstogo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.1.0",
    "eslint": "^8.22.0",
    "expo": "~45.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.3.0",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.69.4",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.18.9",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^8.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.3",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.30.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^4.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

any idea why ?

Comment: Are you sure it's supposed to be `quotes: [2, "double", { avoidEscape: true }]` and not `"quotes": [2, "double", { avoidEscape: true }]` ?

Comment: it doesn't work without the double quotes inside the js file

Comment: Your eslint rule works for me, which makes me think you have a conflicting rule from another package, most likely prettier. If you uninstall prettier, do you still get the error?

Comment: yeah i ran 'yarn remove prettier' and still getting the error, i am so confused why i am getting this error